# Computational complexity of median filter in image processing

Tags: algorithms, image-processing, statistics

I found this paper http://nomis80.org/ctmf.pdf, that describes an efficient algorithm for applying a median filter to an image. Though this works for non-HDR images, I am not sure how well it scales in HDR scenarios. The concern is that if the dynamic range is extended, it is no longer true that the number of intensity values is constant with respect to the filter radius $r$, but rather proportional to $r^2$, at least when $r < 2^{12}$ pixels. The question is whether it is possible to construct a more efficient algorithm than runing `nth_element`, whitch is $\mathcal{O}(r^2)$ on consecutive image blocks, and if so, how? Can I take advantage of previously computed values in order to aviod doing the same operations over and over again?